# Как включить заполнение экрана при повороте в ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, интерфейс, позиционирование

Нарисовал `UI` в `Xcode`. В портретном режиме он отображается корректно. Когда экран я поворачиваю, только в левой части (чуть более половины) есть элементы `UI` - на правой части - белый фон (то есть подложка по умолчанию).

**Вопрос:** Как сделать так, чтобы при повороте экрана в правая часть тоже полностью заполнялась?

Comment: Для этого существует auto layout. Можно почитать к примеру https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

Comment: А эта ссылка, разве не по swift'у? Я просто на objective-c разрабатываю.

Comment: Там есть ссылка на раннюю версию документации, на obj-c: https://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1 То на чём пишете роли не играет, если конечно UI не формируется программно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одним из возможных решений (и похоже, не самым лучшим), могло бы быть развёртывание приложения на крупноформатном экране. К примеру, в файле `storyboard` перейти на вкладку `view controller`, оттуда - в инспектор атрибутов. Далее, выставить широкоформатную ябло-продукцию (я выставил 1/2 ширины экрана `ipad`), чтобы на `iphone` нормально запускалось в пейзажном режиме.  И убрать флажок *Resize view from nib*. Рисунок прилагается: [image: Пример]